# C# double.ToString("F4") no padding if less than 4 digits?

Tags: c#, double, tostring

Is it possible to avoid padding in double.ToString("F4") if the double only has less than 4 digits after the decimal?

eg

```
double a = 1.1;      //MyToString("F4") -> "1.1"?
double b = 1.11111;  //MyToString("F4") -> "1.1111"
```

Comment: maybe something like `.Trim("0")`

Comment: `ToString("#0.0###")`? Might need to know more here. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

Comment: @madreflection ToString(".####") does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need a leading `0` if the value is between -1 and 1 (exclusive)? If so, you'll need the "`0`" before the dot.

Comment: In that case, do we need the leading '#' in "#0.####"?

Comment: No. That was an off-the-cuff guess but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need `ToString("#.0###")`& it will pad with 0 in the end or will round it of . See https://dotnetfiddle.net/PbL3Yc